Controlling A Servo Motor Using PySerial in PyCharm to Pico
I am trying to control a servo motor using a Raspberry Pi Pico through PySerial in PyCharm. I have connected the Pico to my computer and am using PySerial to send commands to it. However, I am encountering issues with getting the servo motor to respond correctly to the commands.
What I Tried:
i haven't tried pyserial in pycharm and unsuccessful established communication with the Raspberry pi Pico..
trying to upload a basic MicroPython script to the Pico that reads serial data and moves the servo accordingly.
Sent angle values (0-120) from PyCharm to the Pico through PySerial.
Here is a sample of the code I am using in PyCharm to send the data:
import serial
import time

# Open serial connection to the Pico
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the connection to establish

# Send angle values to control the servo
for angle in range(0, 120, 10):
    ser.write(f'{angle}\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(1)

ser.close()

Here is the MicroPython code running on the Pico:
import machine
import time

servo = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(15))
servo.freq(50)

def set_servo_angle(angle):
    # Map the angle to duty cycle
    duty = 40 + (angle * 90) // 120
    servo.duty_u16(duty)

while True:
    if machine.UART(0).any():
        angle_str = machine.UART(0).readline().decode().strip()
        try:
            angle = int(angle_str)
            set_servo_angle(angle)
        except ValueError:
            pass


I expected the servo motor to rotate to the specified angles (0-120 degrees) in response to the serial commands sent from PyCharm. The servo should move smoothly between the angles as it receives the new commands.
What I've Achieved So Far:
I successfully programmed the board's LED using the MicroPython plugin.
The MG996r servo motor is fully functional when controlled via the Thonny IDE.
What I've Achieved So Far:
I successfully programmed the board's LED using the MicroPython plugin.
The MG996r servo motor is fully functional when controlled via the Thonny IDE.
Future Plans for the Project:
I plan to integrate a webcam for object detection (recyclables). Once an object is detected, it will send a signal to the Pico, which will trigger the servo to open the trash lid.
